# Is ethereum patented?

Tags: patent

I'm not sure if this question is on topic here or not, but looking at the [white paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper) and its [contributors](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper/_history), is Vitalik the original and only author?

Did he file a patent for the algorithm or just posted the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different components of Ethereum are to be licensed in different ways, which are described on the [Licensing](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Licensing) page on GitHub. (Note "to be" as it appears there's still some uncertainty.)

In short:

- The core infrastructure (e.g. libethereum, libp2p, etc.): **MPL or LGPL license**
- Applications (e.g. Solidity): **GNU General Public License**
- Middleware (e.g. ethereum.js): **Affero license (LGPL variant)**

There seems to be some debate concerning whether [FOSS software can be patented or not](https://www.fenwick.com/FenwickDocuments/Patent_Rights.pdf) (surely not?), but given the nature of the Ethereum project, the contributions made to it by the community, and the fact that it could be forked by anyone at any time, I doubt a patent for the software we currently know as Ethereum could/would be applied for.